# jQuery UI is not initialized in jQuery page load handler (rarely)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, document-ready

Our web site logs client javascript errors. A small percentage of site visitors get a JS error in our home page $() handler:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

Clearly jQuery is loaded, but the $().dialog() function (jQuery UI) does not exist. The index.html file has the script tags at the end of the body, loading jQuery first, then jQuery UI like all the examples show it:

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ctg.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The last JS file has the handler like:

```
$(function() {
    setJSErrorHandler();
    ...
    $(".dlg").dialog({  //<--- TypeError here
        autoOpen : false,
        modal : true,
        ...
    });
});
```

I have looked at many, many questions on document-ready event handling and jQuery but I don't see how this error can happen with the above HTML and JS code structure. It works for all but a few visitors, making me wonder if there is a subtle timing issue, or maybe an old browser with faulty implementation?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `.dialog()` call within a `$(document).ready()` callback?

Comment: According to https://api.jquery.com/ready, `$(handler)` is the same as `$(document).ready(handler)`.

Comment: This would suggest that jQueory UI is not being loaded or disrupted. What is in `jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js` or why is it custom?

Comment: It was produced with the jQuery UI ThemeRoller which produces a JS file with that naming convention.

Comment: @user3191192 I would try using the standard jquery UI files for testing: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: @user3191192 any chance you'd want to use a more recent version of jQuery and UI?

Comment: @user3191192 I am unable to replicate the issue with the standard sources: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/28od8b0o/ This would suggest there is something failing or wrong in your JS sources.

Comment: I have updated to the latest of both jQuery (3.1.1) and jQuery UI (1.12.1). Since there seems to be no breakage in our site, I put this into our production server. We typically see a few of these errors per week, so we'll see if this solves anything...

Comment: Got the failure again today using the latest jQuery and jQueryUI libraries. Looking at the server access logs I see the client did a GET on all the expected JS files. We trap such errors and present an error page where the user can reload our main page. The client did that and the second time it failed again. They tried again, and the 3rd time it loaded without errors. I am going to add code to capture the users browser/version and maybe find a way to reproduce this problem.

Comment: Still getting occasional failures (1 or 2 per week). Our JS info capture shows the following:
<pre>
http://www.cabintechglobal.com/js/ctg.js (line 1581, column 3)

TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

Stack Trace:
{anonymous}()@http://www.cabintechglobal.com/js/ctg.js:1581:3
g/g/

Client Details

userAgent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0
appCodeName: Mozilla
appName: Netscape
appVersion5.0 (Windows)
platform: Win32
prototype:undefined

URL: http://www.cabintechglobal.com/

</pre>